# How to learn Django 1.6..?

Tags: django

I hope this question is soon gonna be closed as non-constructive. But I am asking this because I've had a lot of search on Google and stack-overflow but I didn't have a satisfying answer. 
All other questions like this have been asked years ago and as things are changing rapidly I though this was necessary.

So what I am asking is what resources should I follow. I'm done with tutorial app and now I want to go further and master this beautiful framework but next the thing django's website tells me to go to is the documentation. But isn't reading the documentation a bit cumbersome task(Its like depth-first-search. You go deeper and deeper until you reach the end).

I just want to know if there are any advanced tutorials aimed at django 1.6 and higher. Some screen-casts or some book(other than django-book which quite outdated, as they say on the first page) like ones of Android that take you through by making different apps.

Comment: Well I think everything about Django start here [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/). I bought 2 books about django and the lesson I learnt, is that django's documentation is that good that you don't need to look for any book or whatever.

Comment: Indeed, I can advice you 1000 times to go through the tutorial, at least the first 5 steps. You'll have the basis to be more curious and find more about Django by yourself, on SO and on the official doc of course. Manolis C. has given you the right link!

Comment: I already said I've done that tutorial..

Comment: @Darwesh It's great you are finding Django a useful framework. However, your question is very broad, i.e. not a a specific programming question. I would simply recommend starting your own project and consulting the Django docs when you get to something you don't understand. For times when you are really stumped, well, that's what SO is for! Good luck!

Comment: I am asking about advanced tutorials. Because the basic knowledge I've got from this tutorial can help make the web app that I want but I want to learn other cool stuff in django that can even make my code better. But in this case when my app would be working fine with the basic knowledge, why would I find a need to look in to documentation to improve it.. ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have quite recently (well, about a year ago) started using Django, so I think I have a good idea what it is to start using Django and to learn it. I mainly had a PHP background, with a bit of experience in a few other programming languages, but no Python.

The tutorial is the first place to start. You have already finished the tutorial, so now you know the absolute basics and you're ready to start fooling around. There are many topics to learn about, all with a lot if information. The documentation covers a lot of topics in a basic, understandable way, as listed on the [topics page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/). This is where you should spend most of your time while getting a grasp of Django. Once you start building your own (dummy?) project, you will come across a lot of the topics discussed in the documentation, and there's a lot to learn from those pages.

If the topic pages don't cover your problem, it's time to start looking around. The [API-reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/) provides detailed description of a lot of Django mechanics, but it doesn't really cover best practices and solutions to common problems. For best practices and common problems, Google and Stack Overflow are your best friends: it's very likely someone once ran into the same problem you have, and came up with a good solution.

If one of your problems isn't covered in any of those sources, you can always ask here on SO. I also like to dig around Django's [source code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/1.6/django) to get a better understanding of the way things work, and this often helps me solves more complicated problems.

Anyway, the best step to learning Django after finishing the tutorial, is to work on your own Django project while keeping the [topic guides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/) at hand. That will cover most of the things you need to learn.

Answer (score -1):

This is the link to the django tutorial on the official django website: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

The tutorial explains how to write a django app, explaining in detail how to set up a django project and the different aspects to django development.