# starting django project advice

Tags: python, django

Background: I have an idea for a side project that I can best describe as a combination between expedia.com/kayak.com and wikipedia. The main website would use APIs, web scraping/screen scraping, or other technologies to populate search results generated from external sources. I would also create a community (like wikipedia) where users could edit content inside the search result ( I apologize if I'm being too vague)

Problem: I have limited experience in python and Django and I feel watch youtube tutorial is not benefiting me. Could anyone offer some advice on projects I can work on or tutorials I can watch so that I can build confidence to work on this project of mine. Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to learn Django 1.6..?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253392/how-to-learn-django-1-6)

Comment: there is a good 'getting started with Django' section in the SO documentation

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to build polls app from [Official django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/)
that will cover most of the aspects. Also I would insist you finish [Tango with Django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/).

Another approach would be to go part by part of your website's features.:

want to implement user sign up login ? : figure out how to implement that.

want to implement sms notification? search for django packages and learn how to use them in your project.(since you feel learning from tutorial is not enough)

P.S I would suggest you do all your work in[Virtual environments](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) seperate for each projects.